# aws: command not found after installing AWS CLI v2 on Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli

After installing awscliv2 2.2.0 (with pip3 install) I'm getting

```
/bin/sh: aws: command not found
```

which awsv2 returns /usr/local/bin/awsv2 .

Previous version 1.25.60 was in /usr/local/bin/aws.

I've tried to add

```
RUN echo 'alias aws="awsv2"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

to Dockerfile but without much luck.

What should I add to the code or how should I adjust it to be able to use aws commands with awscliv2?

Comment: not exactly the answer; but your shell is `sh` but you are adding alias to `.bashrc`. that's why you don't have luck with alias

Comment: Thank you @Felix, tried RUN echo 'alias aws="awsv2"' >> ~/.shrc, but aws command is still not found